# TFS 2012 How to build a solution with external dll reference

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am new to TFS trying to set up the build on TFS 2012.

My Directory Structure is

```
Web
   _Common
       thirdparty
          Telerik
             RadControls
                 2011.3.1305.40
                     Bin40 (All Dll's)
       Utilities.NET4.0
          Utilities(VB Project folder)
             All Files & Folders 
             Utilities.vbproj

   FOO(Folder Name which is also application Name)
      1(Custom Versions 1 per client Bases)
          FOO -All Files & Folders 
          FOO.sln
      2(Custom Versions 2 per client Bases)
          FOO
          FOO.sln
      3(Custom Versions 3 per client Bases)
          FOO -All Files & Folders 
          FOO.sln
```

Below is my solution file for Custom Version 1

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-F184B08FC61A}") = "FOO", "http://localhost/FOO/1/FOO", "{1B4DD106-50B1-44E1-AB1F-E9F175E995F8}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "false"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0"
        ProjectReferences = "{A6EE09B0-8E91-4D7F-A513-4A45A8EF93A8}|Agility.Web.Utilities.dll;"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/FOO/1/FOO"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "FOO\1\FOO\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\FOO\1\FOO\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/FOO/1/FOO"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "FOO\1\FOO\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\FOO\1\FOO\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "FOO\1\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-F184B08FF28F}") = "Utilities", "..\..\_Common\Utilities-.NET4.0\Utilities\Utilities.vbproj", "{A6EE09B0-8E91-4D7F-A513-4A45A8EF93A8}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {1B4DD106-50B1-44E1-AB1F-E9F175E995F8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {1B4DD106-50B1-44E1-AB1F-E9F175E995F8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {1B4DD106-50B1-44E1-AB1F-E9F175E995F8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {1B4DD106-50B1-44E1-AB1F-E9F175E995F8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A6EE09B0-8E91-4D7F-A513-4A45A8EF93A8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A6EE09B0-8E91-4D7F-A513-4A45A8EF93A8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A6EE09B0-8E91-4D7F-A513-4A45A8EF93A8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A6EE09B0-8E91-4D7F-A513-4A45A8EF93A8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Things to Note :

- IIS Setup on Local machine

  - FOO = WebApplication
  - Utilities = virtual folder

How do I achieve this :  FOO has reference to dll's under Bin40

I have tried achieving this but I am not able to get it run using the default template.

Thanks for the help.

Solution :

I updated the build definition.

In Workspace I mapped the working folder

```
 $/Web/Main/_Common: $(SourceDir)\_Common
 $/Web/Main/_Common/thirdparty/Telerik/RadControls/2011.3.1305.40/Bin40:$(SourceDir)\FOO\1\FOO\Bin
 $/Web/Main/FOO/6: $(SourceDir)\FOO\6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file reference is using a relative path in the project file.

Also, make sure your workspace mapping for your build is downloading the entire Web root directory from your example.

If that isn't working we'll need to see the error you are getting, and how you referenced the relevant DLL.

Comment: I have updated the post with the solution but I am not sure if that's the correct way to reference the second part i.e. The telerik dll's

Comment: Can you not just have a single entry in your workspace mapping that does: $/Web/MAIN -> $(SourceDir)